# Email signature received as text and links in Gmail and Windows Mail App

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, email-signature

I'm trying to add a signature to my emails from Outlook Web App, I create the following html:

```
    <table class="x_MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
<table class="x_MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:53.55pt">
<td colspan="5" style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt; height:53.55pt">
<p class="x_MsoNormal" style="line-height:105%">
    <a href="http://www.infofort.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span style="color: windowtext; text-decoration: none; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;">
    <img naturalheight="86" naturalwidth="248" src="https://owa.ae.aramex.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetFileAttachment?id=AQMkAGJjYTFkM2FiLTdkNTQtNGIzNS1iOGJhLWY5YTFiNGViYgA3MDQARgAAAw75utOqxa5Pi3BqXsgRMHkHALGtf1K3tM1Mjw52Qob3HswAAAIBDAAAALGtf1K3tM1Mjw52Qob3HswAAAIJggAAAAESABAA%2BYjCoofiTE%2BLvcqGOkILwA%3D%3D&X-OWA-CANARY=mtiHdUk-mkq71fSkRruUDMACP_Q68dUIWHa8mYvznkAvj2ey9GU5JA49F7OIoJ8pmc_Mh7I_BJU.&isImagePreview=True" border="0" width="165" height="57" id="x_Picture_x0020_1"  style="width: 1.7222in; height: 0.5972in;"></span></a><span style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;"></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
    <p class="x_MsoNormal" style="line-height:105%">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/infofort-llc" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span style="color: blue; text-decoration: none; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;">
            <img naturalheight="25" naturalwidth="25" src="https://owa.ae.aramex.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetFileAttachment?id=AQMkAGJjYTFkM2FiLTdkNTQtNGIzNS1iOGJhLWY5YTFiNGViYgA3MDQARgAAAw75utOqxa5Pi3BqXsgRMHkHALGtf1K3tM1Mjw52Qob3HswAAAIBDAAAALGtf1K3tM1Mjw52Qob3HswAAAIJggAAAAESABAAez5Fteh0NU%2BnazZ7eTVEdA%3D%3D&X-OWA-CANARY=mtiHdUk-mkq71fSkRruUDMACP_Q68dUIWHa8mYvznkAvj2ey9GU5JA49F7OIoJ8pmc_Mh7I_BJU.&isImagePreview=True" border="0" width="17" height="17" id="x_Picture_x0020_2"  style="width: 0.1736in; height: 0.1736in;"></span></a><span style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;"></span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
<p class="x_MsoNormal" style="line-height:105%"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/InfoFortMEA" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span style="color: blue; text-decoration: none; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;">
    <img  naturalheight="25" naturalwidth="25" src="https://owa.ae.aramex.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetFileAttachment?id=AQMkAGJjYTFkM2FiLTdkNTQtNGIzNS1iOGJhLWY5YTFiNGViYgA3MDQARgAAAw75utOqxa5Pi3BqXsgRMHkHALGtf1K3tM1Mjw52Qob3HswAAAIBDAAAALGtf1K3tM1Mjw52Qob3HswAAAIJggAAAAESABAAtaDyopkmzECUADtqdmuUWw%3D%3D&X-OWA-CANARY=mtiHdUk-mkq71fSkRruUDMACP_Q68dUIWHa8mYvznkAvj2ey9GU5JA49F7OIoJ8pmc_Mh7I_BJU.&isImagePreview=True" border="0" width="17" height="17" id="x_Picture_x0020_3"  style="width: 0.1736in; height: 0.1736in;"></span></a><span style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;"></span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
<p class="x_MsoNormal" style="line-height:105%"><a href="https://plus.google.com/+Infofort/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span style="color: blue; text-decoration: none; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;">
    <img  naturalheight="25" naturalwidth="25" src="https://owa.ae.aramex.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetFileAttachment?id=AAMkAGJjYTFkM2FiLTdkNTQtNGIzNS1iOGJhLWY5YTFiNGViYjcwNABGAAAAAAAO%2BbrTqsWuT4twal7IETB5BwCxrX9St7TNTI8OdkKG9x7MAAAAAAEMAACxrX9St7TNTI8OdkKG9x7MAAAAAAmCAAABEgAQALypwETw4gZJiOEUFGRdKpc%3D&X-OWA-CANARY=mtiHdUk-mkq71fSkRruUDMACP_Q68dUIWHa8mYvznkAvj2ey9GU5JA49F7OIoJ8pmc_Mh7I_BJU.&isImagePreview=True" border="0" width="17" height="17" id="x_Picture_x0020_4"  style="width: 0.1736in; height: 0.1736in;"></span></a><span style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;"></span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
<p class="x_MsoNormal" style="line-height:105%">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/infofort" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <span style="color: blue; text-decoration: none; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;">
            <img naturalheight="25" naturalwidth="25" src="https://owa.ae.aramex.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetFileAttachment?id=AQMkAGJjYTFkM2FiLTdkNTQtNGIzNS1iOGJhLWY5YTFiNGViYgA3MDQARgAAAw75utOqxa5Pi3BqXsgRMHkHALGtf1K3tM1Mjw52Qob3HswAAAIBDAAAALGtf1K3tM1Mjw52Qob3HswAAAIJggAAAAESABAA%2FltCfkeH5ESfcUUkR0vvJQ%3D%3D&X-OWA-CANARY=mtiHdUk-mkq71fSkRruUDMACP_Q68dUIWHa8mYvznkAvj2ey9GU5JA49F7OIoJ8pmc_Mh7I_BJU.&isImagePreview=True" border="0" width="17" height="17" id="x_Picture_x0020_5"  style="width: 0.1736in; height: 0.1736in;">
        </span>
    </a>
    <span style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;"></span>
</p>
</td>
<td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
<p class="x_MsoNormal" style="line-height:105%"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/InfoFort/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span style="color: blue; text-decoration: none; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;">
    <img  naturalheight="25" naturalwidth="25" src="https://owa.ae.aramex.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetFileAttachment?id=AQMkAGJjYTFkM2FiLTdkNTQtNGIzNS1iOGJhLWY5YTFiNGViYgA3MDQARgAAAw75utOqxa5Pi3BqXsgRMHkHALGtf1K3tM1Mjw52Qob3HswAAAIBDAAAALGtf1K3tM1Mjw52Qob3HswAAAIJggAAAAESABAADSBGJ1Cc8USmwJVIEC6CEQ%3D%3D&X-OWA-CANARY=mtiHdUk-mkq71fSkRruUDMACP_Q68dUIWHa8mYvznkAvj2ey9GU5JA49F7OIoJ8pmc_Mh7I_BJU.&isImagePreview=True" border="0" width="17" height="17" id="x_Picture_x0020_6"  style="width: 0.1736in; height: 0.1736in;"></span></a><span style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;"></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
<p class="x_MsoNormal" style="line-height:105%"><span style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;">
    <img naturalheight="122" naturalwidth="1" src="https://owa.ae.aramex.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetFileAttachment?id=AQMkAGJjYTFkM2FiLTdkNTQtNGIzNS1iOGJhLWY5YTFiNGViYgA3MDQARgAAAw75utOqxa5Pi3BqXsgRMHkHALGtf1K3tM1Mjw52Qob3HswAAAIBDAAAALGtf1K3tM1Mjw52Qob3HswAAAIJggAAAAESABAAYl14W4l5tkavwRHtfgHcGQ%3D%3D&amp;X-OWA-CANARY=mtiHdUk-mkq71fSkRruUDMACP_Q68dUIWHa8mYvznkAvj2ey9GU5JA49F7OIoJ8pmc_Mh7I_BJU.&amp;isImagePreview=True" border="0" width="1" height="81" id="x_Picture_x0020_7"  style="width: 0.0069in; height: 0.8472in;"></span><span style="font-size: 12pt; line-height: 105%; color: rgb(31, 73, 125); font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont;"></span></p>
</td>
<td width="275" style="width:203.5pt; padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
<p class="x_MsoNormal" style="line-height:120%">
    <b><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif ; color: black;">Yehia Abdel Salam</span></b>
    <br/>
    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif ; color: black;">Digital Sales Manager</span><br>
    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont; color: black;">Mob: +20 12 23461340</span><br>
    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont; color: black;">Tel: +02 16915</span><br>
    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; color: rgb(220, 41, 30);">InfoFort – Egypt – Cairo</span>
</p>

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Which looks great when i open the html in Chrome or Edge. I copied all elements by opening Chrome and clicking on Ctrl+A then Ctrl+C and Paste it Outlook Email Signature box using Ctrl+v. Now when I send it, it looks okay on Outlook webmail in the *Sent Items*, but on Gmail and Windows Mail app, I receive a bunch of links like the attached. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do you set the HTML signature in Gmail and Windows Mail app, or send email with this signature to a Gmail account and an account set up in Windows Mail app?

Comment: @SteveFan i’m setting the signature in Outlook 365 Web App actually